# What is the c.d.f of median?

Tags: probability

Given the simple random samples $X_{1}, X_{2}, X_{3}\sim Unif(0, 1)$, let
$Y$  is the median of $X_{1}, X_{2}, X_{3}$.
What is the c.d.f of $Y$?

Comment: Do you know how to find the CDF of the minimum or the maximum of the sample?

Comment: You've been here long enough to know that posts like this which only include an isolated problem statement without any context are not well-appreciated. Please [edit] your question.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Using the [Order Statistics](http://www.math.ntu.edu.tw/%7Ehchen/teaching/LargeSample/notes/noteorder.pdf) Theory you easy find that

$$f_{X_{(2)}}(y)=3!y(1-y)=6y(1-y)$$

$y \in (0;1)$

This is the PDF... If you are intersted in the CDF, just integrate it

---

FYK: $X_{(2)}\sim Beta(2;2)$